# Is it okay to duplicate website homepage with different URL and blocked from indexing to drive ads traffic to?

Tags: seo, search-engines

On my website, I have a landing page (only contains a call-back request form with no other data but the logo).

And I am driving clients from ADs to it, but this page as clients say has low authority.

So, we wanted to create a duplicated home page (that already contains a call-back request form) with a different URL (`https://www.websitename.com/new-homepage-no-follow`).

**WE WILL BLOCK THIS PAGE FROM BEING CRAWLED**

In order to gain higher authority and convince people to interact and submit the form.

Is it okay to do so? or this will put me in trouble regarding the SEO point of view?

Answer (score 2):

On your ad variant I would just set your main homepage as your `canonical url`.

```html
<link rel="canonical" href="example.com" />
```

In the future, I would consider implementing query strings / url parameters to control your advertising landing pages.

Comment: Do you mean like I just add this line without even blocking the page from being indexed by Google or crawled by spiders?